# Speeding Up Query on a Time Series Table. It's Slow to get (MAX - MIN) Aggregation Value

Tags: postgresql, performance, aggregate, postgresql-9.6, time-series-database, query-performance

## Question

How to improve this query to increase the speed of the query shown below from **30+ seconds** to milliseconds? I am using **PostgreSQL: v 9.6.6**.

## Context

I have a time series table `buildings.hispoint` that stores historical data for data points in a table `buildings.point`.

I need to aggregate the `Max(value) - Min(value) as aggregation_value` for different time ranges (e.g. year to date) for a large collection of data points.

This proves to be very slow and needs improvement.

## Table Structure of `buildings.hispoint` **(20,210,129 rows)**

```
CREATE TABLE buildings.hispoint (
    id int,
    value float,
    datetime timestamp,
    point_id …
    CONSTRAINT foo FOREIGN KEY (point_id)
    REFERENCES buildings.point (point_id),
    …
);
```

## Query

```
SELECT COUNT(datetime) AS id, 
MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS aggregation_value
FROM buildings_hispoint
WHERE point_id = 44 
AND buildings_hispoint.datetime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-05-02 09:18:14';
```

## QUERY PLAN

```
Aggregate  (cost=160967.11..160967.12 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=21713.720..21713.720 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=7817 read=66145 dirtied=1
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on buildings_hispoint  (cost=5705.82..159708.13 rows=167864 width=16) (actual time=161.733..21585.478 rows=19783 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (point_id = 44)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3474664
        Filter: ((datetime >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (datetime <= '2018-05-02 09:18:14+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 306305
        Heap Blocks: exact=46580 lossy=26488
        Buffers: shared hit=7817 read=66145 dirtied=1
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on buildings_measurementdatapoint_ffb10c68  (cost=0.00..5663.85 rows=306589 width=0) (actual time=139.360..139.360 rows=326088 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (point_id = 44)
              Buffers: shared read=894
Planning time: 40.504 ms
Execution time: 21717.750 ms
```

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the indexes and execution plan generated using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486)

Comment: As per your advice I have added the query planner debug information. I have also changed the data type of the value field from char to float.

Comment: Does the table have any index? Does it have a  `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An index on `(point_id, datetime, value)` will likely speed up the query, as it will only have to do an index seek, read only the relevant part of the index and also have available (from the index) all the values of the `value` column to calculate the `MIN` and `MAX`.

An index on (A) `(point_id)` or (B) `(point_id, datetime)` would need to also find the read the relevant tuples from the table, in order (A) to filter them for the datetime range and (A and B) to read the values of the `value` column.

Answer (score 4):

You're casting to float in runtime,

```
MAX(value::float) - MIN(value::float) AS aggregation_value
```

Just change the `value` type to float if you want that effect.

```
ALTER TABLE buildings.hispoint
  ALTER COLUMN value
  SET DATA TYPE TO float;
```

Also what's the point of `ORDER BY 1 asc` if you're only returning one row?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion with changing the data type. I have accomplished that and now the query is taking much less time. But it is still quite long. I have added the query planner debug information. Would appreciate if you could take a look at it.